# ADFC-12000: State ID in request is invalid for the current session

Tags: java, oracle-adf

Hello i have a problem in session when i login to my project at the first time it works well without any error but when i logout and login secondly this error show to me
`ADFC-12000: State ID in request is invalid for the current session.`
this is my logout code:

````
      FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
                    HttpSession session = (HttpSession)context.getExternalContext().getSession(true);
                    session.invalidate();
                    return "Login.jspx"; ```
i'm using oracle **jdeveloper 12.2.1.4.0**
i need your help
thanks..
````

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your keeping the state in the request. Try to add the following to your logout function and if it doesn't help take a look at your weblogic.xml > Session > Encode session Id using query params.

```java
ExternalContext ectx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
HttpSession session = (HttpSession)ectx.getSession(false);
session.invalidate(); //Should be surrounded with try catch
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)ectx.getRequest();
ServletAuthentication.invalidateAll(request);
ServletAuthentication.killCookie(request); //If you use authentification cookies
return "Login.jspx";
```